# How to restrict input for a trinidad input date control?

Tags: textbox, datepicker, readonly, trinidad

I have a  control on a page, and would like to restrict users entering dates directly into the textbox associated with the date picker.

Is there any way to do this.

Thanks and Regards,

Wriju

Comment: Add attrribute readOnly. [Read this](readOnlymyfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_inputDate.html)

Comment: readOnly would restrict users from selecting the dates by clicking on the date picker image.
I would like to allow users to choose a date from the dialog which opens up when one clicks on the calendar image but the associated textbox should not accept any input...
I'm sorry that the question didn't explain the requirment clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be adding `onkeydown="return false"` to your `<tr:inputDate/>`. This will prevent users from typing in the date field.

```
<tr:inputDate chooseId="chooseDate1"
              value="#{myBean.myDate}"
              onkeydown="return false"/>
<tr:chooseDate id="chooseDate1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks jasper, that works as a solution but I came across a "Green Eyed Devil" who hacked the HTML and removed the onkeydown attribute of the rendered textbox.

So I had to use the body tag's onload event to remove the textbox and use a label in its place.